# power function. Why set result = 1 at start of loop?

Tags: javascript, function

I have no problem with the code I am posting below as **it works fine** but I was just hoping someone could explain to me why `var result =  1`.

The way I understand it now is that "result *= base" is the same as "result = result * base." With this being the case wouldn't the power also just be the number inputed into  exponent paramenter? 1 * 10 = 10 etc... Thanks in advance!

```
var power = function(base, exponent) {
  var result = 1;     // <--- Why this???
  for (var count = 0; count < exponent; count++)
    result *= base;
  return result;
};

console.log(power(2, 10));
```

Comment: Are you aware of the `Math.pow` function? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_pow.asp :-)

Comment: @Joe Please don't link http://w3fools.com. MDN is much better. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow

Comment: @Scimonster for something as simple as `Math.pow`, it doesn't really matter. In general I link to MDN, but ... `Math.pow`, man

Comment: @Joe Even here, MDN does a better job.

Comment: @Scimonster it does, but it's irrelevant because both do enough for the OP. I guarantee you that someone who's not aware of the `Math.pow` function will get just as much information from W3S. Yes, MDN is better, but for this, W3S is good enough. People see W3S and are instantly all touchy-feely about it, but just think of the context because it sometimes just doesn't matter

Comment: @Joe: I'm not dogmatic about this, but one difference is that linking to w3schools does give them a small boost in SEO. w3schools comes back as the first result when I search for `javascript math.pow` with MDN second (and MSDN third).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because result needs to be a number with a value before you can multiple it by another number. `NaN * base === NaN` and `0 * base === 0`

Try removing it and see what happens:

```
var power = function(base, exponent) {
  var result;
  for (var count = 0; count < exponent; count++)
    result *= base;
  return result;
};

console.log(power(2, 10));    // output: NaN
```

> The way I understand it now is that "result *= base" is the same as "result = result * base." With this being the case wouldn't the power also just be the number inputed into exponent paramenter? 1 * 10 = 10 etc...

Your `result *= base` is in a loop. So each time you go through the loop you are updating the `result` variable with a new value. So first time through the loop you have:

```
result = 1 * 10
```

And the next time you have:

```
result = 10 * 10
```

And the next:

```
result = 100 * 10
```

And so on...

If you moved the `var result = 1` part inside the loop, then your function would be broken as `result` would get reset on each iteration.

Comment: @Joe: Yes, that was the question the OP was asking. They were asking why it was set to 1.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I read the title as "Result = 1" meaning "why is the result 1?", which just misled me for the rest of the question :P (because it's obviously not 1)

Comment: @Joe: Agreed that the question tripped up several people and wasn't as clear as it could be. I edited it a little to try and make it clearer.

Comment: Sorry for confusing people. I'll get better but no need to down-vote me! Just trying to learn here

Comment: @DanielH I didn't downvote, but a moment ago I saw it had been DV'ed, and re-upped you, because it's not a DV-worthy question :)

Answer (score 1):

result is initialized to base to the power zero, which happens to be 1.

Then you multiply it exponent times by base, resulting in base^exponent.

so 2^10 = 1 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 .. 10 times.

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways of solving the problem,

Either you start from 1 and multiply the base with itself n times (like in your example), or you start from base and you multiply n-1 times:

```
var result = base;
for (var count = 0; count < exponent - 1; count++)
  result *= base; 
//this will return wrong result if you call power(2, 0)
```

The first case is obviously better since the base can be 0.

The shortest answer to the question is because `base ^ 0 = 1`

Comment: Thanks for answering. Would you mind providing me with examples of the two different ways? Sorry if I'm asking too much.